# Differentiating and finding limits as a single process?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So let's say I have a function defined as $f(x) = e^{3x}$. Then it can be differentiated using particularly the chain rule to $e^{3x}\cdot 3$. And here comes the part that makes me wonder:

So the derivative of any function $g(x)$ is defined as $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x + h)-g(x)}{h}$. Then, why can't I just calculate the derivative of $f(x)$ by $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{3(x+h)}-e^{3x}}{h}$?

Instead, $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{3(x+h)}-e^{3x}}{h} = e^{3x} \neq 3\cdot e^{3x}$. Why  do I have to separately apply different rules, namely the chain rule in this case but possibly a lot more, instead of just being able to replace a function into $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x + h)-g(x)}{h}$ and find its value as $h \to 0$ in "one step". Similarly, why can't you just calculate the limit of all functions in "one step" - it seems like you have to separately apply different rules (or limit laws).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we have that
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{3(x+h)}-e^{3x}}{h} = e^{3x}\cdot \underbrace{\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{3h}-1}{h}}_3=3e^{3x}.$$
And in fact, also, applying the different rules of derivation helps a lot to avoid you having to calculate limits that at first glance seem impossible. How do you compute the following limit?
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\arctan (x+h)-\arctan(x)}{h}$$

Comment: But see this - https://www.symbolab.com/solver/function-inverse-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bh%5Cto0%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7B%5Cleft(3x%2Bh%5Cright)%7D-e%5E%7B3x%7D%7D%7Bh%7D%5Cright). It says that the result is different :/

Comment: You made a mistake writing the exponent, it should be $ 3 (x + h) $ instead of $ 3x + h $.

Comment: oh, my bad... But so the laws / rules that make you differentiate or calculating the limits multiple times for "sub expressions" instead of just calculating everything in one process using possibly heavy algebraic operations are just there to simplify things or?

Comment: Exactly. These rules help us to differentiate a function a thousand times more efficiently than by the definition. In fact, those rules can easily be proved using the definition with the limit.

Comment: ahhhhh perfect! Thanks man